# How to add required field validation to SXA Tags field?

Tags: sxa, validation

I created SXA Tags in the Sitecore and I know how to add this tag to an item but I want to add the required field validation to the Tag fields, so I can not save the items without adding tag to it.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select Required validation rule for all the validation rules section in the template for your desired field:

- Quick Action Bar
- Validate Button
- Validator Bar
- Workflow

Best would be to duplicate OOTB Required validation rule and set "Result" parameter to "FatalError". Name the validation rule as "Fatal Required"  or something similar.

In other words, set `Result=FatalError` inside the Parameters field of your duplicated Required validation rule:

[image]

Then you can use it as a validation rule and it will disable content editors to save pages without specifying Tags field:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of how to do maximum length validations in SXA

Comment: Take a look on "Max Length 40" validation sample rule and create similar with your desired maximum length value

Comment: Once a rule is created do you assign it partial design or Page design Level in SXA

Comment: You need to assign it on field level

Comment: since its SXA and field is reusable applying validation at field level would assign this validation rule to all components.

Comment: That is a new requirement. This is not mentioned in your question. Of course this will set validation for that field but you wanted it based on question.